# Copy all SVG's on the page to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, svg, copy

I wanted a one click button to copy all of the SVG's on the page. I could not find an existing question on the site for copying multiple SVG's.

The solution I've provided below works, however could always be improved upon. For example to take a detail parameter list to control which SVG's to grab, what size they should be and other information to include.

Answer (score 0):

The below example will grab all the SVG's in this case they are all selectable from the className highcharts-root.

Then it creates a canvas, loops through the SVG's, converts them to PNG's and adds them to the canvas. Finally it will copy that canvas to the clipboard.

One part which could be improved is the forced timeout at the end to make sure all the images have loaded onto the canvas.

This version will also paste the images in grid 2 by X grid like so:

| Image | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Image | Image |
| Image | Image |
| Image | Image |

This can be adjusted as needs fit.

```js
export async function copyPNGs() {
    const svgElements = document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-root");
    const gutterSpacing = 15;
    const width = 650;
    const height = 400;
    const background = "#eee";

    // Create a temporary canvas element to render the SVGs as PNGs
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width * 2 + gutterSpacing * 3;
    canvas.height = (height + gutterSpacing) * Math.ceil(svgElements.length / 2) + gutterSpacing;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Fill the canvas with a light gray background color.
    if (context) {
        context.fillStyle = background;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    // Render each SVG as a PNG and draw it on the canvas.
    for (let i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
        const row = Math.ceil((i + 1) / 2) - 1;
        const column = i % 2;
        const svg = svgElements[i];
        const svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
        const img = new Image();
        const isEven = column === 0;
        img.onload = function () {
            const dx = column * width + (!isEven ? gutterSpacing : 0) + gutterSpacing;
            const dy = row * height + (row !== 0 ? gutterSpacing * row : 0) + gutterSpacing;
            context?.drawImage(img, dx, dy, width, height);
        };
        // Convert the SVG to a data URL and set the src of the image element to it.
        img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData)));
    }

    // Wait for a second to make sure all images are loaded, then convert the canvas to a blob and copy it to the clipboard.
    setTimeout(() => {
        canvas.toBlob(async (blob) => {
            if (blob === null) {
                alert("Could not copy the charts");
            } else {
                await navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": blob })]);
            }
        }, "image/png");
    }, 1000);
}
```